# fsck from util-linux 2.26.2 how to fix it

Tags: upgrade, fsck

I have upgraded from 15.04 to 15.10. After that finished, I have this message in black screen

```
fsck from util-linux 2.26.2 /dev/sda2: clean. 362332/30236672 files, 81578087/120945920 blocks
```

What does that mean and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It means that the integrity of the file system on `/dev/sda2` was checked and no error was found. There's nothing to fix here, because it's just a notification that there was no problem.

Comment: As you're a reputation 11 user: if this answers your question, don't forget to click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means "yes, this answer is valid"!

Answer (score -2):

you should reinstall your desktop. 
prees ctrl+alt+f1

login with your user and pass.

if you use uinty write in terminal:

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

if use Gnome :

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-gnome-desktop`

Comment: The `fsck` utility is just a filesystem check. Reinstalling the desktop environment doesn't seem like an answer.

Comment: This was bug and I found it in launchpad