# Can't change the owner of a folder

Tags: permissions, 18.04, automount, chmod, chown

I want to change the owner of a folder. The path to to that folder is `/mnt/8A30AA8B30AA7DB7/Books`. I want to take the ownership of that folder to change the permissions. The folder currently belongs to root. I tried the following connamds but none seem to work.

1. `chown apoorv_potnis -R Books`
2. `sudo chown apoorv_potnis:apoorv_potnis -R Books`
3. `sudo chown apoorv_potnis:apoorv_potnis -R /mnt/8A30AA8B30AA7DB7/Books`
4. `sudo chown -R apoorv_potnis: /mnt/8A30AA8B30AA7DB7/Books`

The terminal displays `chown: changing ownership of '/mnt/8A30AA8B30AA7DB7/Books': Read-only file system` and other files in the folder but does not actually change the ownership. Whenever I check the properties of that folder or the sub-folders, the owner is shown to be root and I cannot change the permissions or delete any file of that folder. How can I take the ownership of the folder? I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with dual boot Windows 10.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/197459/how-to-fix-sudo-unable-to-open-read-only-file-system

Comment: @damadam When I typed `sudo fsck -Af -M` in my terminal, it displayed `fsck from util-linux 2.31.1`. I don't know what that means as I'm new to Ubuntu.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/692758/fsck-from-util-linux-2-26-2-how-to-fix-it

Comment: I've encountered similar problem on auto-mounted partition. The answer of **Greg Kramida** helped me a lot, you can find it here https://askubuntu.com/a/958491/830248

Comment: Clue: `Read-only file system` .. you can not update or delete from a Read-only file system.

Comment: Is this NTFS, not a Linux format. You can only use chown on Linux formats. Windows formats get default permissions only from mount. And if NTFS and read only probably Windows fast start or hibernation. See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by [user7547272](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037767/cant-change-the-owner-of-a-folder/1037814#comment1689529_1037767) and [oldfred](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037767/cant-change-the-owner-of-a-folder/1037814#comment1689486_1037767), I disabled Fast Startup and hibernation on Windows 10, ran `chown` and `chmod`. Then I followed what was written in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/958491/830248) and my problem was solved.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as though the directory is mounted as Read Only, instead of Read Write.
Unmount the directory, remount it as R/W
Review the man pages on mount for further details.